# selenium is working fine when i work with webdriver,but I can't find the geckodriver excutable anywhere

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I have code as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and this is working fine!
but when I search the location of geckodriver of firefox

```
find / -name "gecko*" 2>/dev/null
```

it has nothing,I am confused by how selenium works if there isn't webdriver excutable anywhere, but if there is,why I cant find it??

Answer (score 0):

To find the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* programatically you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import os
  print (os.path.abspath("geckodriver.exe")
  ```

Comment: @CaoYue Your comment is not helping me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback?

Comment: sorry about that, I wanna find the location of "geckodriver.exe" file,it seems I can not find it ,your code will print the absolute dir name + /geckodriver.exe in my system. which indicate there is no geckodriver excutable in my system. but the problem is my selenium code in the question works fine

Comment: @DebanjanB it's not the OP's duty to help you improve your answers

Answer (score 0):

from the command `..2>/dev/null` it seem you are using linux, right? To locate `geckodriver` in your system Try running command

```
which geckodriver
# or
locate geckodriver
```

in case you cannot run `locate` install it

```
apt-get install mlocate
# or
yum install mlocate
```

Then update the file location database using

```
mlocate
```

Comment: I used the commands in your answer, it finds nothing,the contradiction of how my webdriver.Firefox() works fine but could not find the engine is driving me nuts.